# How to retrieve examples from Merriam Webster dictionary API in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am trying to parse a JSON response with information relating to a specific word in ReactJS. I have been able to retrieve the word definition from the response but not the word's examples. I cannot seem to access the property "suppl" in any capacity let alone the "examples" that are nested within it.

Below is the partial format of the JSON response according to the Merriam Webster API documentation. The full response format can be found here: https://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary

```
"suppl":{  
 "examples":[  
    {  
       "t":"the building\u0027s high ceilings and {it}voluminous{\/it} spaces"
    },
    {  
       "t":"a writer of {it}voluminous{\/it} output"
    }
 ],
```

I have tried doing this in several ways all of which either display undefined or throw an error stating "examples" is an undefined property

```
fetch('https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/cat?key=MY_API_KEY')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then( (result) => {
                
alert("Example 1: "+result[0].suppl.examples[0]);
alert("Example 2: "+result[0].suppl.examples.t);
alert("Example 3: "+result[0].suppl.examples);
alert("Example 4: "+result[0].suppl.examples[0].t);
alert("Example 5: "+result[0].suppl);
});
```

What am I missing here? Is something wrong with my structure or something else that I am not seeing?

Comment: Why `result[0]`? This does not appear to be an array, `result` is an object, that should have `suppl` on the top level.

Comment: Using ```result[0]``` instead of just ```result``` is what previously allowed me to begin accessing the data in the response.  For example, I retrieved the definition like this: ```alert("Definition: "+result[0].shortdef[0]); ``` The same line using ```result``` instead of ```result[0]``` throws an error

Comment: Okay, so you get an array of such objects back, apparently (not exactly clear from that documentation.) But then `result[0].suppl.examples[0].t` should work. What do you get, when you log `result` to console? Has it actually been successfully decode into an object at this point? Or is it somehow still in string form, perhaps?

Comment: @CBroe logging result to console displays ``` Example 7: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ``` . As for whether it has been converted yet I am not entirely sure to be honest with you (I am still quite new to using APIs and ReactJS). Everything from fetching the response to displaying it is in the code I originally posted

Comment: `[object Object]` is usually what you get, when an object has been force into a string context. But that could be due to the fact that you are doing string concatenation in your log statements there. Instead of `console.log("Foo: " + someObject)`, you should be using `console.log("Foo:", someObject)` _"Everything from fetching the response to displaying it is in the code I originally posted"_ - but without an API key, we can't actually reproduce this to see what result you are actually getting.

Comment: @Andy sorry I probably should have specified. In the example, I am hard coding the word "cat" into the fetch URL as the word to search for, so the API would be receiving a word. Logging ```result``` to the console displays ```[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @CBroe I have edited my concatenations to use commas instead of +'s like you suggested but it does not seem to have changed anything. Is there any other useful information I could share that might help with determining a fix?

Comment: I've just tested this - the API documentation is wrong and you are right. _Another however_: the response doesn't have any `suppl` properties at all which is why you're getting `undefined` when you try and log them. I tested this against their example "voluminous" and that didn't have any either.

Comment: @Andy that is very interesting indeed, it had never even occurred to me that the documentation itself might be the issue. I would not have figured that out by myself so thank you for that bit of info. How would you suggest I proceed from here? Or is it maybe time to thrown in the towel for this one?

Comment: I got so annoyed by this I sent them an email :) I'll let you know if I hear anything back. There are other dictionary APIs out there. Perhaps you could continue with one of those? Kind of depends on the data you're relying I suppose.

Comment: @Andy It is actually for a task that is for the programming boot camp I am currently doing so using another API is not really an option as they specified we must use this one. All good though, I will report it to them too. Thanks so much for your help, you've saved me a lot of wasted time :)

Comment: No problem. Best of luck with the coding.